# Expand/Open Excel Ribbon menu with VBA

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

I have a custom tab in Excel (2013). On the tab, there is a menu that has multiple toggle buttons. It would be beneficial from a user standpoint that the menu would stay open until they are done with all their selections.

So I am looking for a way to keep the menu expanded after clicking any of the toggle buttons and the only way to close the menu is to click away from the menu. One thought that I had/looking for, is there any way through vba to expand a menu in the ribbon. So I would include that at the end of the sub-routine for each toggle button.

Comment: I don't think there's a logical pattern here: 1. How would you define they're done with their selection? 2. When you need to re use it, how would you trigger it? 
Excel automatically hides the bar and only expands by hoovering it over, I think that may work better in this case then.

Comment: There's no default functionality for this. The Ribbon you can basically use to call different macro's from. To get what you describe - You'll be in a world of pain to code it. I'd suggest using a `UserForm` for this, which you open from the menu, e.g. a "settings menu" for your Add-in or whatever it is you're building. A UserForm would also be more consistent with the other menu's behavior in Excel.

Comment: Sgdva, this is common feature that I have seen in other software (such as SolidWorks). In excel if you click away from the menu, the menu disappears. That is exactly what I want to do. I want the menu to stay visible if the user activated one of the toggle buttons only. If they click anything else, it will collapse the menu.